# Windows: Hotkey assistance

Tags: windows-xp

Well, I'm wondering is there's any way to link a single key on my keyboard to a file. I wish to execute the file upon pressing the key. I tried using the built in shortcut hotkey system and it didn't work out for me. It really needs to be one single key.

Answer (score 1):

[Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) may do the job - I used it to trigger an action upon "double-pressing" the "alt" key (ahk script below). I'm pretty sure you can trigger an action by pressing a key only once also, but might be difficult to find an otherwise unused key for that.

```
Alt::
KeyWait, Alt
KeyWait, Alt, D, T0.12
If ErrorLevel = 1
    Return
Else
    Run, c:\example.exe -aparameter
```

Answer (score 0):

What is possible is enable sticky keys and thus eliminating the need of pressing multiple buttons at once.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It's an interesting idea for sure, however the application won't run using Microsoft's built in shortcut thingy, at least not for the key I wish to use.